# How to increase the size of a Docker volume?

Tags: docker

I want to use a Docker container as a backup server (mainly as an openssh daemon). For that I need to attach a volume to it in order to store the data. In the docs I could only find how to attach the volume, not how to set its size.
So I attach a volume with:

```
docker run -p=2222:22 -d -v /backup docker-ssh
```

and do a `df -h` inside the container and get this:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none                          101G   20G   76G  21% /
tmpfs                         7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
shm                            64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root  101G   20G   76G  21% /backup
```

The first thing that strikes me is the exact same size and use of `/` and `/backup`. Is it a coincidence or are they the very same file?
But what I really want to know is how to increase the size of `/backup` because I need more space for this backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker volumes are just links to host volumes, so they are same size as host directory is.

If you mount a larger volume, more space will be available for the container.

`/` and `/backup` are same size as they points to same storage device.

Comment: so you say that `df -h` is not accurate in this case and I could fill `/backup` with more than its reported total size?

Comment: It should be accurate. If you inspect your container on host, `docker inspect containerName`, then you should see real directory location on your computer (for example, `/var/lib/docker/volumes/fac362...80535/_dat`). To mount different drive as `/backup`, use this format: `/mnt/hdd2:/backup`, where `/mnt/hdd2` is your backup path on host.

Comment: Thanks, I wrongly assumed the volume was on another underlying file system. Now that I checked, I realized the underlying file system for this volume is indeed 101G in size. So it makes sense.